# Skip scenario after first example (python Behave)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, testing, automated-tests, python-behave

Hi :) Is it possible in behave to skip scenario outline if first example fails with specific error? I have scenario with multiple examples but if it fails at the beginning with specified error than there is no need to run the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think cucumber does not offer an option like this. What you could do is at the step where you are expecting the fail to occur, fill the featurecontext.

Firstly, you will need to tag the scenario outline. Lets say you tag it with

```
@test
```

Then, at the step where you are expecting an assertion to go wrong, you fill the featurecontext with a certain value.

After that, whenever the assertion goes wrong, and your feature context is filled with a certain value, you can use the Before hook for the @test scenario. In this Before hook, you check the content of the featurecontext. If it is filled with your assertion fail value, you can then skip the scenario, but I can't seem to find a proper way to skip in cucumber.

I found this on the internet, but no idea if it works properly..

```
Before('@test', function (scenario, callback) {
callback(null, 'pending');
});
```